# How to read only the first parameter in typedef struct?

Tags: c

sorry I am new to C and can not even explain the question clearly..
here is the code

```
typedef struct _ft_device_list_info_node {
    ULONG Flags;
    ULONG Type;
    ULONG ID;
    DWORD LocId;
    char SerialNumber[16];
    char Description[64];
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
} FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE;
```

I got a pointer *chanInfo which basically points to the structure FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE. I want to output certain stuff depending on the Flags in FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE, so I decide to use "switch()", but what should i put as the condition for switch? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you should not be dealing with peripherals and stuff if you don't even know the syntax for accessing a struct member...

Answer (score 3):

The straight answer is this:

```
switch (chanInfo->Flags)
{
case Something:
    ...
    break;
}
```

...but I can't help feeling there's more to it than that...

If `Flags` is actually a bitmask, which is quite likely judging by the name, then a `switch` is probably the wrong thing to use.  You might want to do something like this:

```
if (chanInfo->Flags & FLAG_ONE)
{
    // FLAG_ONE is set...
}

if (chanInfo->Flags & FLAG_TWO)
{
    // FLAG_TWO is set...
}
```

A `switch` is for mutually exclusive cases, whereas flags are usually not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Aww... I didn't even understand what OP wanted... and now it hurts...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I would write:

```
switch(chanInfo->Flags)
{
    case value1:
        <do stuff>
        break;
    ...
}
```

But I highly suggest to follow some guide or book to learn things step by step.